# Best Practices for Storing an Expression

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store an expression (operators and operands) in a container. The best implementation I can think of is storing them in a string.

For example:

```
2 30 + 5 *
```

would be stored as

```
"2 30 + 5 *"
```

However, this incur the problem that, when extracting from the string using

```
string tk;
string expr;
stringstream e(expr);
e >> tk;
```

if there're any missing space, "2 30+ 5*", the error handling part would be some kind of distracting. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you have to break up the expression into its parts (tokenize), do that first and then store an array/vector of tokens.